# angular 4 - Bootstrap not working in lazily loaded modules declared in routes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-routing

I am using bootstrap3 in my angular 4 project. I have a DashboardComponent which contains a nav menu in it. I declared a route as

```
{path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
```

in the routing module and bootstrap nav menu is not showing properly. If I change the route configuration to

```
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
```

then its working fine.

Below are the screenshots for both working and non-working cases. What could I fix this issue?

working case
[image]

Non working case
[image]

`dashboard-routing.module.ts`

```
export const dashboardRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'dispatches', component: DispatchesComponent },
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
      ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the `dashboard.component.html`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar" data-color='red' data-image="" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
    <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/sidebar-4.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-panel">
    <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>  
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer-cmp></footer-cmp>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { CustomMaterialModule } from './modules/custom-material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:  [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CustomMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [CustomMaterialModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap:  [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`dashboard.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomMaterialModule } from './../modules/custom-material.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SidebarModule } from './../sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './../shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule} from './../shared/navbar/navbar.module';
import { MODULE_COMPONENTS } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DispatchesModule } from './dispatches/dispatches.module';
import { TransactionsModule } from './transactions/transactions.module';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      CustomMaterialModule,
      DispatchesModule,
      TransactionsModule,
      SidebarModule,
      NavbarModule,
      FooterModule,
      DashboardRoutingModule,
    ],
    exports: [CustomMaterialModule],
    declarations: [ DashboardComponent, MODULE_COMPONENTS ]
})

export class DashboardModule{}
```

Comment: What does your dashboard-routing.module look like? While you're at it add in the dashboard.module

Comment: @Z.Bagley updated the question with dashboard-routing.module

Comment: Are those two images the same spot? What does your browser console say? My guess is that you're using a selector to load your `DashboardComponent` and not actually routing to it, which means you can completely delete it from your lazy loaded route, but you need to declare it in your `app.module`. What does the code that displays that area look like, and what is the error in console?

Comment: @Z.Bagley Yes they were same spot. and console shows no errors at all. and No I am not using a selector as I specified a `DasboardComponent` in `dashboard-routings.module`. I have a `router-outlet` in the `app.component.html` where dashboard.component is being rendered and dashboard has another `router-outlet` in which the child components are being mounted based on the selected child route.

Comment: @bhanu Can you please add more code? Add your app.module, app-routing.module and dashboard.module, as your current routing config should work fine...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo updated question with the required code.

Comment: @bhanu do you get any errors in console with the non working case? what is MODULE_COMPONENTS?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo No I am getting errors in that case as I am not able to navigate due to absence of nav links(dashboard routes). Even if I directly enter the address in the browser its working fine.